# Can I signal multiple threads simultaneously with pthread_cond_wait(,)?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

I am writing various code snippets and see what happens. The code below was intended to delay all threads until all reached a certain point in the code and then make each print a distinctive number. Since the threads all do that, the numbers should occur in a random order.

My current problem is that I keep they threads busy waiting. If the number of threads gets big, the program slows down significantly.

I would like to change that by using signals, I found `pthread_cond_wait()` for that, however I don't see how one would use that to signal all threads that they would please wake up.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

#define threads 10

int counter=0; 
pthread_mutex_t lock; 

void handler(void *v) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    counter++;
    printf("%d\n", counter); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);   
    while(counter != threads); // busy waiting

    printf("I am first! %d\n", v); 

}


int main() {

    pthread_t t[threads]; 
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++) {       
    pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, handler, (void*) i); 
    }
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++) {       
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

EDIT: I changed the code to the following, however, it still does not work :/

```
pthread_mutex_t lock; 
pthread_cond_t cv; 

void handler(void *v) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);
    printf("I am first! %d\n", v); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}


int main() {
    pthread_t t[threads]; 
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++) 
        pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, handler, (void*) i); 
        sleep(2); 
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv); 
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++) 
        pthread_join(t[i], NULL); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: See usage example: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html

Comment: Note that although `pthread_cond_signal()` has "signal" in its name, it hasn't much to do with "signals" as that term is normally used in C context.  But that doesn't mean that a condition variable won't do the job you want.

Comment: Your code is broken. If `counter` is protected by the mutex, you can't access it without holding the mutex. Yet your `while` loop does exactly that. This mistake, in practice, allows the compiler to "optimize" `while (counter != threads);` to `if (counter != threads) while(1);`.

Comment: Use `pthread_cond_broadcast` to signal all threads that are waiting on `pthread_cond_wait`

Comment: However you happened upon the idea, combining a condition variable with your mutex is a good way to go.  HOWEVER, if your example is representative of what you want to do in that you want to wait for a specific number of threads to all reach the same point, then release all of them to proceed, then you might also look into using a [barrier](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait).

Comment: If the code is then optimised to ´if (counter != threads) while(1);`, then why is the code then still working "properly"? I am aware it's not necessarily good, but for learning purposes well enough.

Comment: It's working "properly" if you didn't expect this optimization and improperly if you did expect the optimization. I think it's actually unfortunate that it happened to do what you happened to want because that can cause you to learn that it's okay to access an object that's protected by a mutex without holding that mutex. It's not -- the results are unpredictable and what you think is "working properly" may not agree with what I think or, worse, what the compiler things.

Comment: @Imago, it is *not* good for learning purposes!  Quite the opposite.  Learn good habits and proper practices from the start, so that you do not need to *un*learn bad ones later.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that is the reason I ask. I have not yet enough experience to write code by good habit and proper practice, in particular, because I don't know yet, what is all possible. 
+ I strongly believe, that you can learn from errors and bad code, if someone more experienced shows weaknesses and offers improvements.

Comment: Sure, @Imago, you can learn from errors, including coding errors.  But if someone who knows better points out such errors to you, and you respond by saying it's good enough for learning purposes, that conveys to me that you are not interested in learning from them, or that you do not perceive them as the errors they are.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, If I am not interested in learning from my errors or not perceiving my errors as such, then why did I ask for help in the first place? I don't care about my ego, I just want to become better, even if it means putting myself in the lion's den by asking on SO.

Comment: Re, "If the code is optimized...why is it still working?" That optimization is _allowed_ by the language standard, but it is not _required_.  When threads in your program share a variable with no _synchronization_, then we say that your program depends on _[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)_ (UB).  A program that depends on UB may work just fine in one instance, but it may fail to work if you change the OS, if you change the hardware platform, if you change which compiler or which compiler options you use, if you change any line of code, etc.

Comment: Put another way.  A program that depends on UB is _wrong_. period. Even if it happens to work for you today, there's no guarantee that it will work for you tomorrow or, that it will work for anybody else.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and Solomon Slow: Interesting. Falling into the trap of undefined behaviour happens scarily easy. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

use `broadcast()`?

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html

The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` function shall unblock all threads currently blocked on the specified condition variable `cond`.

The `pthread_cond_signal()` function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable `cond` (if any threads are blocked on `cond`).

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't get the threads to block. Will try again. But thank you.

Comment: @Imago Yeah, good luck. I couldn't get condition variables to work on one of my personal projects, probably a deadlock was occurring somewhere during creation.

Comment: I appended my try using pthread_cond_wait, however my output is still bad. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: You signal once to wake up a single thread. The single thread wakes up and goes out of scope, the rest of the threads are just waiting. Add a pthread_cond_signal(&cv); at the end of the handler method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to `pthread_cond_broadcast()` might be the following.

You define a read-write mutex and lock it in write in the main thread before creating the other threads. The other threads will try to acquire a read-lock but since the main thread have a write-lock they will be blocked.

After the creation of all thread the main-thread releases the lock. All the other threads will be waken up and since many read-locks can coexist the will execute simultaneously (i.e. no one will be locked).

Code might be something like:

```
pthread_rwlock_t lock; 

void handler(void *v) {
    if ((res = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock)!=0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("I am first! %d\n", v); 
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
}


int main() {
    pthread_t t[threads];
    //First acquire the write lock:
    if ((res = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock)!=0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }        
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++)
    { 
        pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, handler, (void*) i); 
        //it is not clear if you want sleep inside the loop or not
        // You indented it as if to be inside but not put brackets
        sleep(2); 
    }
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock); 
    for(int i =0; i < threads; i++) 
        pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&lock);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try posting the matching remove_from_buffer code.

Better yet, Short, Self Contained, Correct Example
Make a short main() with two threads.
One thread adds to the buffer at random intervals.
The other thread removes from the buffer at random intervals.

*Example*

> CELEBP22

```
/* CELEBP22 */                                   
#define _OPEN_THREADS                                                           
#include <pthread.h>                                                            
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <time.h>                                                               
#include <unistd.h>                                                             

pthread_cond_t cond;                                                            
pthread_mutex_t mutex;                                                          

int footprint = 0;                                                              

void *thread(void *arg) {                                                       
  time_t T;                                                                     

  if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0) {                                        
    perror("pthread_mutex_lock() error");                                       
    exit(6);                                                                    
  }                                                                             
  time(&T);                                                                     
  printf("starting wait at %s", ctime(&T));                                     
  footprint++;                                                                  

  if (pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex) != 0) {                                  
    perror("pthread_cond_timedwait() error");                                   
    exit(7);                                                                    
  }                                                                             
  time(&T);                                                                     
  printf("wait over at %s", ctime(&T));                                         
}                                                                               

main() {                                                                        
  pthread_t thid;                                                               
  time_t T;                                                                     
  struct timespec t;                                                            

  if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0) {                                  
    perror("pthread_mutex_init() error");                                       
    exit(1);                                                                    
  }                                                                             

  if (pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL) != 0) {                                    
    perror("pthread_cond_init() error");                                        
    exit(2);                                                                    
  }                                                                             

  if (pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, NULL) != 0) {                         
    perror("pthread_create() error");                                           
    exit(3);                                                                    
  }                                                                             

  while (footprint == 0)                                                        
    sleep(1);                                                                   

  puts("IPT is about ready to release the thread");                             
  sleep(2);                                                                     

  if (pthread_cond_signal(&cond) != 0) {                                        
    perror("pthread_cond_signal() error");                                      
    exit(4);                                                                    
  }                                                                             

  if (pthread_join(thid, NULL) != 0) {                                          
    perror("pthread_join() error");                                             
    exit(5);                                                                    
  }                                                                             
}
```

*OUTPUT*

> starting wait at Fri Jun 16 10:54:06 2006 IPT is about ready to
>   release the thread wait over at Fri Jun 16 10:54:09 2006

Comment: Calling `pthread_cond_wait` unconditionally is almost always an error. Your `thread` function acquires, but does not release, the mutex. And calling `pthread_cond_wait` exactly once is almost always an error because, at minimum, it doesn't handle a spurious wakeup. Is `footprint` protected by the mutex or not? If so, `main` is broken. If not, what's the predicate?

Comment: It's posted as an example to someone who doesn't know how to use a condition variable properly, and it misuses condition variables fundamentally in at least three ways.